# Elasticsearch High CPU When Idle

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm fairly new to Elasticsearch and I've bumped into an issue that I'm having difficulties in even troubleshooting. My Elasticsearch (1.1.1) is currently spiking the cpu even though no searching or indexing is going on. CPU usage isn't always at 100%, but it jumps up there quite a bit and load is very high.

Previously, the indices on this node ran perfectly fine for months without any issue. This just started today and I have no idea what's causing it.

The problem persists even after I restart ES and I even restarted the server in pure desperation. No effect on the issue.

Here are some stats to help frame the issue, but I'd imagine there's more information that's needed. I'm just not sure what to provide.

Elasticsearch 1.1.1
Gentoo Linux 3.12.13
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.7) (Gentoo build 1.6.0_27-b27)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

One node, 5 shards, 0 replicas

32GB RAM on system, 16GB Dedicated to Elasticsearch
RAM does not appear to be the issue here.

Any tips on troubleshooting the issue would be appreciated.

Edit: Info from top if it's helpful at all.

```
top - 19:56:56 up  3:22,  2 users,  load average: 10.62, 11.15, 9.37
Tasks: 123 total,   1 running, 122 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 98.5 us,  0.6 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.7 id,  0.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  32881532 total, 31714120 used,  1167412 free,   187744 buffers
KiB Swap:  4194300 total,        0 used,  4194300 free, 12615280 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                  
 2531 elastic+  20   0  0.385t 0.020t 3.388g S 791.9 64.9 706:00.21 java
```

Comment: Can you give us more details like your htop logs?

Comment: Added top info (don't have htop installed). Let me know if there's anything else you'd like to see.

Comment: Lucene does some background merging I know.  I'd see if you can take a thread dump when CPU is high,  perhaps you could see what might be taking up the CPU.  Otherwise I'd post to the ES group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andy Pryor mentioned, the background merging might have been what was causing the issue. Our index rollover had been paused and two of our current indices were over 200GB. Rolling them over appeared to have resolved the issue and we've been humming along just fine since.

Edit:
The high load when seemingly idle was determined to have been caused by merges on several very large indices that were not being rolled over on a weekly basis. This was a failure of an internal process to roll over indices on a weekly basis. After addressing this oversight the merge times were short and the high load subsided.

Comment: This is not an answer! It looks more like a comment on what @Andy Prior wrote